# Flutter: How can I hide cookies in webview_flutter (appTrackingTransparency)?

Tags: flutter, cookies, webview-flutter, apptrackingtransparency

Does anyone have experience with webview_flutter & appTrackingTransparency?
The APP was rejected by Apple. The reason is that cookies appear in the webview.

When cookies appears, then appTrackingTransparency then message should open.
If appTrackingTransparency is agreed by user, then cookies should accept.
If appTrackingTransparency is rejected user, then do not accept cookies.

Does anyone have sample code?